# If $\mu(\pi) = 0$ for every plane $\pi$, there is a fair cut perpendicular to the $z$-axis.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The question is the following

> Assume that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. A plane $\pi \subset \mathbb{R}^3$  is a *fair cut* if $\mu$ of both components of $\pi^c$ is exactly $1/2$. Prove that if $\mu(\pi) = 0$ for every plane $\pi$, there is a fair cut perpendicular to the $z$-axis.

I noticed that if $\mu(\pi) = 0$ for every plane $\pi$, it means that $\mu(\pi^c) = 1$ for every plane $\pi$, but I don't know how to use this fact.

I also tried to assume that there is no such a fair cut $z = c$, meaning that $\mu(z>c) \neq \mu(z<c)$ for all the plane $z = c$, but I can't go further from this argument.

I thought of proving that $z=0$ is exactly a fair cut desired, and for any plane $z=c\ $  ($c \neq 0$), we can find a plane $z = -c$ accordingly. Since the events from both side of $z=0$ correspond to each other, they share the entire probability space with equal probability, and it concludes the proof. **However, I don't know whether this is legit.**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t)$ be the measure of the lower half space determined by the plane with $z$-value $t$. Then $f$ is non-decreasing, $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to-\infty$, $f(t)\to 1$ as $t\to +\infty$. Let $t_0=\sup\{\,t\in\Bbb R\mid f(t)<\frac12\,\}$, $t_1=\inf\{\,t\in\Bbb R\mid f(t)>\frac12\,\}$. Show that $t_0\le t_1$ and that every plane $z=t$ with $t_ß\le t\le t_1$ is a fair cut.